# Input argument not working

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am trying to define a loadMedia function using an object of previously defined class LTexture as the first input argument. The second input argument is a string of a filepath.

```
bool loadMedia(LTexture textureName, std::string path)
{
//Loading success flag
bool success = true;

//Load texture

if ( !textureName.loadFromFile(path.c_str()) )
{
    printf("Failed to load texture!\n");
    success = false;
}

return success;
}
```

Then within my main loop:

```
//Load media
    if (!loadMedia(mainCharTex,"dot.bmp") | !loadMedia(Enemy1Tex,"dot.bmp"))
    {
        printf("Failed to load media!\n");
    }
    else
    {
```

However, when I run the program the textures are not loaded. If I type in one of the texture objects (for eg. mainCharTex) where textureName is in the loadMedia function, the texture successfully loads. From this it seems the first input argument is not implemented properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use *bitwise* or in the condition?

Comment: You have a typo. You are using a bitwise OR instead of a logical OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to pass `textureName`by reference so that you can change it inside the function and still have the change available in main:

```
bool loadMedia(LTexture& textureName, std::string path)
                       ^
```

Comment: Thanks StillLearning that did it